# C++: Getting segmentation fault when using else instead of if else

Tags: c++

This is my code to convert infix expression to postfix. In the last if else condition, if I am using `else` then I am getting `Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)` while if I use `else if` and define the `if` condition, then the code is working absolutely fine. I cannot figure out why is this happening. This is for the test case `(a+(b*c))`. Logically, I have covered a-z,A-Z,(,) previously in the if-else conditions and the code should work fine if I use `else` for the operators. I need help here.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int prt(char s)
{
    if (s == '(')
        return 0;
    if (s == '+' || s == '-')
        return 1;
    if (s == '*' || s == '/')
        return 2;
    if (s == '^')
        return 3;
}

int main()
{
    // your code goes here
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--) {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        stack<char> s;

        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
            if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')) {
                cout << str[i];
            }
            else if (str[i] == '(') {
                s.push('(');
            }
            else if (str[i] == ')') {
                while (s.top() != '(') {
                    cout << s.top();
                    s.pop();
                }
                s.pop();
            }
            else if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '^') { //This One
                while (prt(s.top()) >= prt(str[i])) {
                    cout << s.top();
                    s.pop();
                }
                s.push(str[i]);
            }
        }

        while (!s.empty()) {
            cout << s.top();
            s.pop();
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, some feedback on code writing style improvement is appreciated.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=str.length();i++)` -- Using `<=` in a `for` loop is signs of an off-by-one error.

Comment: `prt` does not always return a value. This, combined with looking at the nul terminator of the string because of the off-by-one error, results in the fault.

Comment: `if((str[i] >='a' && str[i]<='z') || (str[i] >='A' && str[i]<='Z'))` -- This is not how to check if a character is alphabetic.  The proper check is `if (std::isalpha(static_cast<int>(str[i])))`

Comment: [Explanation of why Paul is casting characters to integers before calling is `alpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha#Notes)

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: And especially don't if you also [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Combining the two brings out the other's worst aspects, too often resulting in nigh-inscrutable errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie • should be `static_cast<unsigned char>` if the platform treats `char` as signed by default.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The mistake was small but the feedback is what helped me the most. thank you

Comment: @user4581301 The mistake was small but the feedback is what helped me the most. thank you –

Comment: @Eljay -- Yes, you're right.